# Does a many-to-many relationship with a recursive one-to-many in mysql require at least 4 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have the following relationships (Business rules):

- **User_Company** : Many-to-many (multiple companies per user, multiple users per company)
- **Ownership** : One-to-One (For each entry in relationship table, it specifies whether user is an owner or employee. If owner then a percentage must be there)
- **Company_ownership** : One-to-many for company (Recursive relationship), as another company can also be an owner in a company, percentage must be given.

**So ownership or a company can be made up of a number of companies and users.**

So I have developed the following:

[image: one-to-many-recursive]

So does there have to be at least 4 tables for this sort of relationship or can it be simplified.
I feel it is quite complicated and would not be intuitive for another developer? How could it be optimized and elegantly arranged?

Comment: Cannot you have two separate relationships for "employees" and "owners" (rather than merging it into one with a flag)? That way you can also have owners that are also employees, and the ownership percentage can be part of the same relation.

Comment: Yes, so instead of `user_has_company` it will be `user_owns_company` and `user_works_comapany` and we can scrap the `ownership` table. Great. What about the relationship of companies, being owners in other companies?

Comment: I am torn between keeping `company_ownership` and merging it with `user_owns_company` (so that would have both a owning_user_id and a owning_company_id, one of which would be NULL. that would make it easier to query/tally ownerships in a single query)

Comment: You've managed to adequately explain the whole thing to us in ca. 100 words - so what's the problem?

Comment: I agree with the combining into one table, however having a `NULL` field makes it `unnormalised`, regarding foreign key relationships or something but I don't think it has an effect on performance. So I will go with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think ownership and employment are different concepts, that would be more advised to have them separated.
Think about John who is one of the owners of `A` company and in the mean time he is the CTO of `A`.
Company and People can have a base to reduce redundancy of entities.
[image]

Comment: Having a base to reduce redundancy is perfect in theory, unfortunatelymy database that stored owners and employees twice, 1 in each table. There is no way to accurately merge them together as the only congruent data is the first name and last name and in that case there may be 2 of the same name, capital letters and middle name problems. So I am really in a bad way and will have to just ensure that data is input from now on in the correct manner. I can't fix that in the past. Your answer is good, however you have not dealt with the `company can be an owner of another company` issue.

Comment: Ownership table have 2 foreign keys,first form company that shows which company is owned, second from person who is the owner, a person may be some people or a company so the issue you have mentioned is answered. Also you will gain more from the design later, like when you need to add an address table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions of [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo)

A separate relationship table was created for owners and employees respectively.
Furthermore, the `company_ownership` and `ownership` tables were removed as having a company as an owner is solved by adding an `owning_user_id` and `owning_company_id` where one will always be null. The percentage figure is added to this relationship table.

See below:

[image: Solved many-to-many relationship problem]

Comment: It seems company-to-company-ownership is missing!

Comment: Yes, it appears that way, but in the company to company case the `user_owns_company` table will have `owning_user_id` as `NULL` and `owning_company_id` will be FK to `company`