# Using fields in relationship table to return as part of Rowset Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This question is related to another: [Does a many-to-many relationship with a recursive one-to-many in mysql require at least 4 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450640/does-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-a-recursive-one-to-many-in-mysql-require-a).

My question is how can I use or return values that are in the junction / relationship table of a many-to-many relationship.

When using:

```
$row = $original_row->findManyToManyRowset('Model_New', 'Model_OriginalNew');
```

I only receive the related record, but I would like to acquire an extra field that is in the junction table of the form:

```
|  id  |  original_id  |  new_id  |  percentage |
```

I would like to get the percentage value, is that possible with `active record` or should I just make use of a `Database Access Object`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$user_row->findDependentRowset('model_Junction_Table_Name');
```